# Rounding off and recast it as integer

Tags: c++, int, double, rounding

```
double num1=3.3;
double num2=3.8;

//print output and round off
cout<<floor(num1+0.5)<<endl;
cout<<floor(num2+0.5)<<endl;
```

My task is to round the number first and then cast it to integer: the output of num1 and num2 after round off should be respectively `3.000000` and `4.000000`. How should I cast it to `int` to get the aboved mentioned answers `3` and `4`?

Comment: You can also use [`std::round`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round) in C++11 or later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cout<<floor(num1+0.5)<<endl;` will print `3.0`. You don't need more cast here, but if you want to do it, use `static_cast`:

```
double num1=3.3;
double num2=3.8;

// to round off
int num1_as_int = static_cast<int>(floor(num1+0.5));
int num2_as_int = static_cast<int>(floor(num2+0.5));

//print output
cout<<num1_as_int<<endl;
cout<<num2_as_int<<endl;
```

More about `static_cast` [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast), and why you should use it instead of C-style casts [here](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#static-cast).

Comment: ya, thanks for pointing out the error, I've re modified the question. but by doing static_cast<int>, it means apply direct casting right?
my lecturer wants me to round off then only cast it to int because she told me by applying direct casting will lead to truncation error

Comment: She is right for negative values. E.g. `-2.6` should be rounded to `-3`: `-2.6+0.5` will be `-2.1` and `static_cast<int>(-2.1)` will be `-2`, a truncation, while `floor(-2.1)` will be `-3.0` (and `static_cast<int>(floor(-2.1))` will be `-3`). I edit my answer

Answer (score 3):

You can declare an `int` variable and assign the result of the `floor`, then output that `int`. The floor is no longer needed either, as the assigning to an `int` does that implicitly.

`int i1 = num1+0.5;`
`cout<<i1<<endl;`

Note that in your current code, `floor()` does not actually help in any way, as you are discarding the result. `floor` is not modifying its parameter, but returning its result, and you are not assigning it to anything. You could have used, for example,
`num1 = floor(num1+0.5);`
and then `num1` would contain the result.

Comment: Previously I've done the same thing as what you did, but my lecturer told me, by directly apply casting it will lead to truncation error, therefore she ask me to round off first and then cast it to int